# Regex to remove blacklisted words from a sentence

Tags: java, regex, oracle

How can I use a regext to filter out a list of blacklisted(Obscene) words, such that 
if a black listed words is like 'Bill Joseph'

```
 Then 'I am Bill Josephine' is valid
    but 'I am Bill Joseph.' is invalid
        'I am Bill Joseph,' is invalid
        'I am Bill Joseph ' invalid
        'I am Bill Joseph<any non alphanumeric>' is invalid.

    Similarly 'I am .Bill Joseph' is invalid
              'I am <any non alphanumeric>Bill Joseph' is invalid.
```

Comment: 'I am Bill Josephine' is valid, but 'I am Bill Josephine' is invalid....O_o

Comment: if Bill Joseph is supposed to be the black listed word then why are any of them valid? It seems like you are more asking how to use regex to make sure a string is a word

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake while posting the question. I've rectified it now.

Comment: I guess I just don't see what the black listed word (bill joseph) has anything to do with the examples

Comment: Read: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) by Jeff Atwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, and this works:

```
String badStrRegex = "\\WBill Joseph\\W?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(badStrRegex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(testStr);  //testStr is your string under test
boolean isBad = m.find();
```

It works!! Tested against all your input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the negation of the alphanumeric character class:

"[^A-Za-z0-9]Bill Joseph[^A-Za-z0-9]"

Using "\W" in place of "[^A-Za-z0-9]" would work in most cases except when there is an underscore before/after the name. So "Bill Joseph_" still would be seen as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the word is surrounded by a word boundary `".*\\b" + badWord + "\\b.*"`

Comment: No he wants any to match 'Bill Joseph' with non-alphanumerics on either side.