# How to match only complete words in Oracle regexes?

Tags: regex, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to remove blacklisted words from a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208178/regex-to-remove-blacklisted-words-from-a-sentence)

How can I use a regex in Oracle to filter out a list of blacklisted (obscene) words, such that if a blacklisted words is like `'Bill Joseph'`

Then `'I am Bill Josephine'` is valid
but `'I am Bill Joseph.'` is invalid
`'I am Bill Joseph,'` is invalid
`'I am Bill Joseph '` invalid
`'I am Bill Joseph<any non alphanumeric>'` is invalid.
Similarly `'I am .Bill Joseph'` is invalid
`'I am <any non alphanumeric>Bill Joseph'` is invalid.

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this here.?

Comment: Believe it or not, but on rare occasions, StackOverflow will not help you in less than 10 minutes...

Comment: Well sorry guys actually that was not my intention i had gone through number of ur threads and found it to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the word-boundary operator:

```
\bBill Joseph\b
```